# Replace Chars inside either side of string?

Tags: c#, regex

OK, I am just going to come straight out with it, I have no idea how to do this, I have tried as much as I can with no success.

To get the string on the left to look like the result on the right with ReGex, the string looks like this,

> `String---String` == `String-String`

This what happens when the middle character is different from the surrounding two characters,

> `String=@=string-String` == `String@string-String`

EDIT, this is also a possiblity,

> `String@@@String` == `String@String`

Any push in the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need a regex for that? `text = text.Replace("-", "")` works fine with everything you've said... if it wouldn't work for other reasons, you need to include that in your question. (And if you've tried things and they haven't worked, you should show what you've tried.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, what happens when the string is like this "---" with the inner string being this "-"? That would produce a fail.

Comment: Okay, so that's precisely why you should include that possibility in your question. Unless we know your requirements accurately, we can't possibly help you. Ideally, you should show your requirements in the form of a [mcve] showing what you've tried, what you wanted to happen and what actually happened.

Comment: You might want to consider what you want the output to be for `a-b-c-d-e`, `a----b`, `a--b--c` etc too. I'm not going to even start to try solving this until I know what the requirements are, as it would be a waste of time.

Comment: @JonSkeet, is it not all in the question even before the edit?

Comment: No, it's not. Your question didn't, and still doesn't, answer what you'd expect the output to be for any of those inputs.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I want to replace the string inside specified chars. Not much else I can say really

Comment: So do you think that completely unambiguously answers what you'd want the output to be for `a-b-c-d-e`, or `a----b`, or `a--b--c`, or `a--b a--c` or `a-b a-c`? I certainly don't think it answers those questions at all. You can choose to argue with me instead of clarifying your question, but I think clarifying your question would be a much more productive way of getting an answer that meets your requirements, if that's your actual goal here. (Any time you have to add a comment to an answer effectively saying "That doesn't answer what I want to do" that means your question is probably vague.)

Comment: @JonSkeet, I updated the question, but I am just repeating what I have already posted.

Comment: So you're not actually going to say what you want the output to be for any of those input strings I gave you? In that case, I know that *I* can't help you, and I'm not going to waste my time by just *guessing* what you actually want.

Comment: @JonSkeet, given your example `a-b-c-d-e`, say I decide that I want to replace the the chars either side of the `b` , then the result would be this `abc-d-e`. Honestly, I don't know how else to explain this to you?????

Comment: What do you mean by "say I decide"? What gets to decide? I'm assuming you effectively want a method accepting a string and returning a string... why would the answer be "abc-d-e" rather than "a-bcd-e" or "a-b-cde" for example? It sounds to me like basically you haven't thought through what your requirements are clearly enough for us to help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158762/discussion-between-kyloren-and-jon-skeet).

Comment: It is easy with regex - [`"Regex.Replace(s, @"^([^-]*)-(.*)-([^-]*)$", "$1$2$3")`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5b%5e-%5cn%5d*%29-%28.*%29-%28%5b%5e-%5cn%5d*%29%24&i=String---String%0d%0a---%0d%0a&r=%241%242%243&o=m).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: For input of "a-b-c-d-e" that gives output of "ab-c-de" whereas apparently the OP wants "abc-d-e". I wouldn't bother trying to tweak it until there are more detailed requirements though.

Comment: @JonSkeet If that is true, that is not in the question. Lets' close it as unclear.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, that regex replaces all the string, plus the string inside as well as the outside???

Comment: I honestly don't know how else I can explain this this other than what I have in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Yes, it's not in the question, it's in the comments where I've been trying very hard to make the OP clarify their question. I've already voted to close as unclear...

Comment: @KyloRen If you want to remove hyphens around `b` in `a-b-c-d-e` why use regex at all? Use `s.Replace("-b-", "b")`. And if you cannot explain what you really need, just have a rest, take a nap, have a snack and come back with a fesh mind. We really do not like guessing games.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, b/c it will remove all the other hyphens . Say I have a string like this "---" that will produce a string of ""

Comment: No, Kylo, if you have `-` in between hyphens, you'd use `s.Replace("---", "-")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, but that will replace all other hyphnes, ie, 1-2-3-4-5-6 will become 123456. I want to have this happen with 1-2-3---4-5-6, then the result will be  1-2-3-4-5-6.

Comment: You should really 1) take a nap 2) reread the comments, 3) remove the post.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, well after a few more days on this, I came to a solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47298549/6283475

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks for the help, this is what I came up with https://stackoverflow.com/a/47298549/6283475

Comment: There's *still* no point in having an answer, because the question is still unclear.

Comment: @JonSkeet, I am honestly lost for words, I don't know what else you are looking for in the question???

Comment: What I've said several times. There's no point in me saying it yet again.

Comment: @JonSkeet, OK, I won't waste any more of your time. I have the solution to my issue and it is tested, so there really is no need to re-hash all this again. Thanks for taking the time to help out, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I was able to figure this out after a couple of days at it.

This issue here is that Regex is that it will match a string as a whole, so if I wanted the exclude a character from a match I could do so by using Regex to drop either the first or last character in the matched string. But unfortunately, you can't not capture a character inside the matched result.

So when I want to match a character either side of another one like below;

[image]

### So from my understanding of RegEx it is impossible.

---

**However**, I was able to use `look-around` to match each character either side, but b/c it was not a single match, it had the undesired result of matching just single characters as well, such as below;

Code is,

```
var match = Regex.IsMatch(text, @"(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9])[=@\-_]|[=@\-_](?=[a-zA-Z0-9])");
```

And the results were this below, which also matched just single characters which was not desired.

[image]

So a change of thinking to the approach (which I don't know why I did not do in the first place, apart from the fact that I was so focused on matching the character either side of the desired character, I could not see the forest for the trees). The approach was to match when two of the same characters came before `Word Characters` or `Digits`, so I used `look-around` again and came up with this;
Here is the code,

```
var match =  Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"[=@\-_]{2}(?=[a-zA-Z0-9])");
```

Whit the result looking like this,

[image]

Which now was what I was looking for. But, that did not solve the issue as when the character or string in the middle was different to the characters either side, to which the above would fail.

So I came up with this, and the answer to my question in my case. It is not a complete match , but matches two different conditions to get the result I needed.

```
var match =  Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, @"(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9])[@\-=_](?=[@\-=_])|(?<=[@\-=_])[@\-=_](?=[a-zA-Z0-9])");
```

And the results are this;

[image]

I don't really care what people thought of the question, but hopefully this answer will help someone tries to do a single match on a `character` either side of a `string` or `character`

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't Replace method work for you? It could be easier to select and replace.
By the way using regex you can try the following code:

```
        string text = "String-MyString-String";
        var pattern = "\\-";
        var match = Regex.Replace(text, pattern, "");
```

EDIT: So you need to remove the first and the last minus char on your string, or you need to replace it? In case you need to remove it you can try this portion of code:

```
        text = text.Remove(text.IndexOf('-'), 1);
        text = text.Remove(text.LastIndexOf('-'), 1);
```

If you need to replace the char, you can use stringBuilder in order to replace the value on the selected spot.

Comment: There's no need to escape `-` in a regular expression unless it's in a range. `Regex.Replace(text, "-", "")` does exactly the same thing.

Comment: We don't know whether it's always just the first and last dashes, as the OP won't clarify various situations. (For example, the output of "a-b-c d-e-f" might be "ac df" or "ab-c d-ef". Your answer would give the latter.)

Answer (score -1):

Oh, I know why you unable to do this. Of course, if you write regex pattern like this:

```
-
```

it won't work, for it to work you need to escape it:

```
\-
```

so it works like this:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\-","");
```

so, yeah this pattern will work. But as Jon Skeet said you can just replace it through much simplier way:

```
var result = str.Replace("-", "");
```

Comment: `-` doesn't need escaping unless it's within a range. `text = Regex.Replace(text, "-", "")` works fine.

Comment: So, I understand corretly that you want "A-B" to become "AB" and "A---B" to become "A-B" ?

Comment: @eocron, yes to the last comment of yours

Answer (score -1):

Without using regex:

```
static string RemoveChars(string input, params char[] chars)
{
  string output = string.Empty;

  for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
    if (!chars.Contains(input[i]))
      output += input[i];

  return output;
}
```

To test the method:

```
string temp1 = "String-MyString-String";
string temp2 = "StringxMyStringyString";
string temp3 = "-x-y-";

Console.WriteLine("Input string: " + temp1 + ", output string: " + RemoveChars(temp1, '-'));
Console.WriteLine("Input string: " + temp2 + ", output string: " + RemoveChars(temp2, 'x', 'y'));
Console.WriteLine("Input string: " + temp3 + ", output string: " + RemoveChars(temp3, 'x', 'y'));
```

And results:

[image: results]

Comment: Not only is this inefficient, but it fails the `String---String` example.

Comment: I missed the String - - - String example. For that you could check for consecutive similar characters. But even then, one would miss the StringxMyStringyString -> StringMyStringString example (as per screenshot).